# Animate fading Background Drawable dynamically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have a drawable (Linear Layout) which has a dynamic color defined as background.

I want to fade the current color to a highlight-color and then fade back to a final-color, which can be different from the start-color
the transition to highlight color should be 0.4s long and from highlight to final 0.2s

I tried it with the `AnimationDrawable` but without success, because this doesn't really support fading.
my current code:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(highlightDrawableId), 400);
animation.addFrame(newBackground, 200);

animation.setEnterFadeDuration(200);
animation.setOneShot(true);
layout.setBackground(animation);
animation.start();
```

Is there any way how I can make this work?

Comment: use a TransitionDrawable

Comment: @pskink the transition drawable only supports 2 drawables, the third one is ignored here. also I can't define transition duration for each frame.

Comment: you have two colors: current color and highlight-color, what third color you mean?

Comment: the current color should fade to highlight and then back to (maybe) another final color

Comment: so use a custom Drawable if TransitionDrawable is not what you want, use ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator for transition effect

Comment: yeah, but how can I implement such a fading in Android?

Comment: android.animation.ArgbEvaluator